# Resolving Multiple Promises with Parallel state (XState)

Tags: javascript, parallel-processing, state-management, statechart, xstate

I have an xstate state machine that has 3 states, idle, waitingForA and waitingForB. waitingForB, in turn is a type of parallel state. I would like to return to initial state of 'idle' on waitingForB is done. How do I accomplish this?

```
idle: {
  id: 'initialState'
},
waitingForA: {
  invoke: { /*Promise*/ },
  onDone: { target: 'idle' },
  onError: { alert(); }
},
waitingForB: {
  type: 'parallel',
  states: {
    waitingForC: {
      invoke: { /*Promise*/ },
      onDone: {
        target: 'success',
        actions: assign({ CreturnCode: (context, event) => event.data, })
      }
    },
    waitingForD: {
      invoke: { /*Promise*/ },
      onDone: {
        target: 'success',
        actions: assign({ DreturnCode: (context, event) => event.data, })
      }
    },
    success: {
      // here, I would like ot go back to initial state of 'idle'
      // based on both CreturnCode and DreturnCode 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to transition out of the parallel state `waitingForB` into the `idle` state once both promise `C` and `D` are done.

There are two ways to accomplish this behavior:

##### 1. Using `Promise.all()` to wrap both promises in the `all()` function.

Using `Promise.all()` [(mdn docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), you can get rid of the parallel state altogether. Instead, you would only have a normal state called sth. like `waiting For C and D` that invokes both promises at once with `Promise.all([promiseC, promiseD])`.

> *This approach can be used if you don't need to differentiate between individual errors that each promise might create. Error handling is performed for both promises in one `onError` event.*

##### 2. Transitioning both child states of the parallel state into their own final state.

In your case, the parallel state has two nested states which each invoke a promise. When the promise of a nested state is resolved, you can use the `onDone` event to transition the nested state to a final state. **Once both nested states have transitioned to their respective final state, an `onDone` event is automatically raised for the parallel state.** There you can define a transition to the `idle` state of the parent machine.

> *The second approach lets you handle the errors of each promise individually which might be preferable if you want to give more specific feedback in the UI for each error.*

```js
const dummyFetch = function (fakeResolveValue, delayInMs) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (Math.random() <= 0.01) {
        reject('some error')
      }
      resolve(fakeResolveValue)

    }, delayInMs)
  })
}

waitingForB: {
  type: 'parallel',
  states: {
    waitingForC: {
      initial: 'loading',
      states: {
        loading: {
          invoke: {
            "id": "getStuffC",
            "src": (context, event) => dummyFetch('C', 1000),
            onDone: {
              target: 'complete',
              "actions": (ctx, ev) => {
                console.log('C done')
              },
              actions: assign({ CreturnCode: (context, event) => event.data, })
            },
            onError: {
              actions: send('handle fetch C error')
            }
          },
        },
        complete: {
          type: "final",
        },
      }
    },
    waitingForD: {
      initial: 'loading',
      states: {
        loading: {
          invoke: {
            "id": "getStuffD",
            "src": (context, event) => dummyFetch('D', 5000),
            onDone: {
              target: 'complete',
              "actions": (ctx, ev) => {
                console.log('D done')
              }
            },
            onError: {
              actions: send('handle fetch D error')
            }
          }
        },
        complete: {
          type: "final",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  // once both promises C and D are complete
  // the onDone event transitions to the `idle` state
  onDone: {
    target: "idle",
  },
}
```

[Here is an example by Matt Pocock](https://github.com/mattpocock/xstate-stream-demo-app/issues/1) using the second approach.